# Why do I get an error reading an RDS file when the file exists and the path is correct?

Tags: r

For this question, it's really hard for me to make a reproducible example because the error happens on the high performance cluster. I am not able to reproduce the error locally.

I have this code:

```
summaries <- list()

for (a in c("A", "B")) {
  for (b in c("C", "D", "E", "F")) {
    for (c in c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05")) {
      summaries[[a]][[b]][[c]] <- readRDS(paste0("/home/user5556/Proj1/Simulation/", a, "/", b, "/", c, "/summary.Rds"))
    }
  }
}

saveRDS(summaries, "summaries.Rds")
```

Running this will return:

```
Error in readRDS(paste0("/home/user5556/Proj1/Simulation/", a, "/",  :
  error reading from connection
```

However, now observe what happens if in the previous block of code we replace `readRDS` with `file.exists()` and print it.

```
for (a in c("A", "B")) {
  for (b in c("C", "D", "E", "F")) {
    for (c in c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05")) {
      print(file.exists(paste0("/home/user5556/Proj1/Simulation/", a, "/", b, "/", c, "/summary.Rds")))
    }
  }
}

[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

When manually typing out the file path, the file is successfully read:

```
readRDS("/home/user5556/Proj1/Simulation/A/C/01/summary.Rds")
```

This reads the RDS file as expected. So what exactly is happening here? It can't be the case that the file path is incorrectly specified, because then the `file.exists()` would return false. It's also not possible that I don't have the permissions to view the file, because then I wouldn't be able to read it in when typing out the path manually. So what's wrong?

Comment: Not a solution, but note that it's best practice to use `file.path` rather than `paste0` when constructing paths.  Also consider `normalizePath`.  Also check you have the necessary permissions with `file.access`.  Existence is not sufficient!

Comment: Good suggestions by @Limey, obviously we can't replicate the issue, when resolved, let us know the issue with an answer below.

Comment: That `c` is also less than ideal object name. Do multiple processes access those files simultaneously? Perhaps build a list of files and run it through `file.info()` ?

Comment: I agree with @margusl, according to syntax highlighting here it seems that `c` is not understood as a variable like `a` or `b`. Maybe consider another name for this variable.

Comment: @margusl It’s totally fine as an object name. R’s scope resolution ensures that we can use it besides the function named `c` without issues. And while this should be done with care in larger scopes to avoid confusion, it’s totally fine in a small enough scope.

Comment: @BarbaraGendron No, the R syntax highlighting of Stack Overflow is simply not very good. There is no issue with the variable name.

Comment: For me it was just the way the error message got truncated right before `c, `, would have expected it to include the whole expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we can't run the code, this is just a guess, but I'd guess one of the files is corrupted somehow.  You tested the first one successfully, but the error doesn't say which one was problematic.

To debug it add debug output to the loop.  For example,

```
summaries <- list()

for (a in c("A", "B")) {
  for (b in c("C", "D", "E", "F")) {
    for (c in c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05")) {
      filename <- paste0("/home/user5556/Proj1/Simulation/", a, "/", b, "/", c, "/summary.Rds")
      cat("Reading ", filename)
      summaries[[a]][[b]][[c]] <- readRDS(filename)
      cat(" successfully!\n")
    }
  }
}

saveRDS(summaries, "summaries.Rds")
```

When the error occurs, you have seen the "Reading" message, but not the "successfully" part, so you will know which file caused the problem.

If it turns out to be the first file, then I was wrong.  But I'm guessing it won't.  You can try `readRDS(filename)` outside of the loop, and see if the error repeats.  I'm guessing it will.

How to fix it isn't clear, but you could just test for that particular filename and skip it, or redo the simulation, or fix file permissions as @Limey suggested.

Comment: Completely unrelated aside, but I am confused why even R core developers use `cat()` and `print()` instead of `message()` for diagnostic output. Simply force of habit, or is there some other reason to avoid it using `message()`?

Comment: Thank you so much! This was indeed the case - one of the files is corrupted. Now I'm on my mission to find out why.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  this isn't a chatroom.